# What happens to my email and OneDrive if I switch from O365 business to O365 home?

Tags: outlook.com, office-365, onedrive, office-online, exchange-server

I originally bought an O365 Business Premium subscription because I wanted email, invoicing and customer management. I found that the later two are only available to subscribers in the United States.

I have paid three times the cost for almost no value. 
I would now like to switch from my premium subscription to a home subscription. My question is, can I switch from exchange to outlook online? Will I be able to keep existing emails? Will I be able to use my custom domain for email?
If I switch over, will I be able to keep my files in OneDrive without first downloading them then re-uploading them? I notice that OneDrive for business has a SharePoint url unlike OneDrive for consumers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I have found that, while it is a delicate process, it is possible to switch your license.
This is how you do it.
First you cancel your current license. You will then be given 30 days to transfer your data. Then you go ahead and buy the alternative tier you want. If this is has the same products as the previous license, you should be able to reactivate your access without interruption.